# how to control/delay subsequent click events on same element

Tags: jquery

```
$navNext.click(function(event, $diff) {
        if(!$diff) {
            var $lastLi = $nav.find('li:last');
            var $lastLiRight = $lastLi.offset().left + $lastLi.outerWidth();
            if ($arrowsNavRight < $lastLiRight)
                $diff = Math.min($lastLiRight - $arrowsNavRight, 50);
        }

        if($diff) {
            $navPrev.show('fade');
            $nav.animate({
                left: '-='+$diff
                }, function(){
                showNavs();
            });
        }
});
```

This is click-handler of one `li` element. This calculation is to navigate a `ul` list of scrollable tabs.
User can click several time on this `li` to reach desired position. but when there is no scope to scroll further I disable this `li`.

Problem is: if user click on this `li` elements too fast then all this click events will be
performed before hiding `li` (calling showNavs function). which can lead to extra scroll of `ul`.

I want to control  subsequent click event on this `li`.
means, if one click is in progress then delay the next click. is there any way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use an `active` variable. If an event fires, first check if `active == false`. If not, do not run through your script. If it is false, then set it `true` and do your stuff. While the script runs, no other event will make this script run. At the end of the script, reset the `active` variable to false to enable a new event to fire.

Comment: I don't want to skip the call if scope for scrolling exist, so I want to delay the call not skip. any jquery solution?

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar kind of issue. i solved it by introducing a loading gif image ... i show it when i want to refrain the user from clicking anything on the page and hide it when the previous action is completed.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function showLoadingBar() {     
$('#overlay').addClass('loading-indicator-overlay');
 $('#loadingbar').addClass('loading-indicator'); }
 function hideLoadingBar() {
 $('#overlay').removeClass('loading-indicator-overlay');
     $('#loadingbar').removeClass('loading-indicator'); } 
</script>
```

And add the following in the body section:

```
<body>
 <div id="overlay"></div>
 <div id="loadingbar"></div>
 ....
 .... 
</body>
```

Add the following style

```
<style type="text/css">
.loading-indicator {
 position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
 width: 80px; 
 left: 50%; 
 top: 50%;
 z-index: 1001;
 background: url( '../images/loading.gif' );
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center; }

//Class for overlay:

.loading-indicator-overlay {
 position: absolute;
  width:100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 1000;
 background-color: black;
 opacity: 0.6; }
 </style>
```

And call the `showLoadingBar()` when user clicks the `li` and call `hideLoadingBar()` when you want the user to be able to click your `li`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="fastclick">Click</a>​
```

jQuery

```
var bool = 1;
var tmr;

$(".fastclick").live("click", function(e) {
    if(bool)
    {
        alert("next click after 3 sec");
        bool = 0;
        tmr = setInterval(doTmr,3000);
    }
});

function doTmr()
{
    if(!bool)
    {
        bool=1;
        clearInterval(tmr);
    }
}
​
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bongs/ZD65a/)